# WPF: get my object index after cell value changed

Tags: wpf, slider

So i have this `Slider` inside my `ListView`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate2">
    <Grid Margin="-6" >
        <Slider Name="sliderColumn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" TickPlacement="None"
                Minimum="0" Maximum="50" Value="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Width="80"
                TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sliderColumn, StringFormat={}x{0}}" FontSize="11" Foreground="White" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<GridViewColumn x:Name="SpeedCell"  Width="100" Header="Speed" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate2}" />
```

And after this `Slider` value changed i can get the new value:

```
private void sliderColumn_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    double val = e.NewValue;
}
```

But i am still missing the most important information i need: the index number of the object the it's `Slider` value changed.

The reason i need the index is because my `ListView` is full with my objects, this objects are inside `RadObservableCollection` and after this `Slider` value changed i want to set the new value base on the index number.

Any suggestions how to find this index ?

Comment: Why not use binding as you did in the `TextBlock` and write the value of the slider back into the object?

Comment: How can i write this value back into my object ? i have this collection and i need the index, maybe you can show me a short example ?

Comment: I assume you want to write it to `Value` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do it to write your value back in what ever object you store your data in. In your case you want to write it into a property of your list entries `DataContext`. It is really simple to do so. You just bind the `Slider.Value` to the property of your backing class.

Now I assume the class you bound your list entries to (so what ever class is on the `ObservableCollection` has a property `SliderValue` that stores a `int`. Like so:

```
public int SliderValue { get; set; }
```

So you bind your slider to the specific property in your backing class.

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Path=SliderValue}" />
```

I removed all formatting code from the slider tag to focus on the relevant bits you need to add.

EDIT: So regarding your last comment `SliderValue` would be `Num`.